# A problem using Bernoulli inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, inequality

> From a magic bean sprouts a little plant one centimeter tall, which grows by 1/30 of its height each day. Demonstrate, using Bernoulli inequality $(1+x)^n\geq1+nx$ that after a year, the plant will have exceeded 40 meters in height.

I write $H(n)=(1+\frac{1}{30})^n$, using Bernoulli inequality I have $1+\frac{1}{365}$ < 4000. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't apply the inequality correctly. But even if you do it correctly, you will get $(1+1/30)^{365}\ge1+\frac{365}{30}\simeq13$, while $(1+1/30)^{365}>157674$.

What can you do then? You may write, with $x=1/30$, $\displaystyle{(1+x)^{365}={((1+x)^p})^{365/p}}$. If we choose $p$ wisely, the inequality may lead to a large enough value for $t=(1+x)^p$, such that we can prove directly that $t^{365/p}>4000$.

With $(1+1/30)^{30}\ge1+\frac{30}{30}=2$, we have then

$$(1+\frac{1}{30})^{365}=\left((1+\frac{1}{30})^{30}\right)^{365/30}\ge2^{365/30}>2^{12}=4096$$

The lower bound is still far smaller than the true value, but it's larger than $4000$.